# Firebase database does not read data when I upload the app in production mode

Tags: java, kotlin

I have my configuration, I have the signature key of the app, both upload and test, but even so, it does not read the data, I use SMS and if the message arrives, but when registering the data, it throws null, I don't know how to do it, it's the first time that This happens to me I have already used some apps but I never went through this.

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.violtecoffe"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.4"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }




    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    viewBinding{enabled=true}
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

    //FIREBASE

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1"


    //LOTIIEEEE

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0"


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

}
```